# Chown silently failing

Tags: raspberry-pi, mysql, usb-drive, chown

I've got a Raspberry Pi configured to run a MySQL database using MariaDB. To ensure that I don't run out of space I want to move the data directory to an external USB hard drive. I followed [an online tutorial](https://www.tecmint.com/change-default-mysql-mariadb-data-directory-in-linux/) and at the end ran the command `systemctl start mariadb` which failed. Upon inspection, I found that line in the log :
`[Warning] Can't create test file /media/pi/DDE\ externe\ test/mysql-data/raspberrypi.lower-test`

I thought it might be a problem with the permissions, so I redid the step of the tutorial where I create the mysql-data directory on the external drive and set its ownership. There I noticed that I couldn't set the owner to user mysql, it would stay as user pi :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/media/pi/DDE externe test $ ls -la
total 8
drwxrwxrwx  1 pi   pi   4096 mars   8 08:31 .
drwxr-x---+ 3 root root 4096 mars   7 15:01 ..
pi@raspberrypi:/media/pi/DDE externe test $ mkdir mysql_data
pi@raspberrypi:/media/pi/DDE externe test $ ls -la
total 8
drwxrwxrwx  1 pi   pi   4096 mars   8 08:32 .
drwxr-x---+ 3 root root 4096 mars   7 15:01 ..
drwxrwxrwx  1 pi   pi      0 mars   8 08:32 mysql_data
pi@raspberrypi:/media/pi/DDE externe test $ sudo chown mysql:mysql mysql_data/
pi@raspberrypi:/media/pi/DDE externe test $ ls -la
total 8
drwxrwxrwx  1 pi   pi   4096 mars   8 08:32 .
drwxr-x---+ 3 root root 4096 mars   7 15:01 ..
drwxrwxrwx  1 pi   pi      0 mars   8 08:32 mysql_data
```

Am I missing something from that chown command ? Or am I making any obvious mistake ?

Comment: What is file system type on your external drive? For now it seems that you are using ntfs or other filesystem that does not support owners.

Comment: That's entirely possible ! I'll try formatting it.

Comment: @DevilaN Formatting the drive did fix the chown issue, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the obvious mistake is that the external drive does not have a filesystem that supports chown.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try formatting it

Comment: While I still get my error message when starting mariadb, at least I did manage to set my folder permissions by formatting my drive to ext4, thanks !