# Can't start MariaDB after moving datadir to external drive

Tags: raspberry-pi, usb-drive, systemctl, mariadb

I am running a MySQL server using MariaDB on my Raspberry Pi. I am expecting the db to grow, so I want to move my db to an ext4-formatted external drive. So far I have been following this online tutorial but at the end I do `systemctl start mariadb` which fails. Looking at `systemctl status`, I see the following error :

```
[Warning] Can't create test file /media/pi/external_drive/mysql-data/raspberrypi.lower-test
[ERROR] Aborting
```

[The MariaDB troubleshooting guide](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/what-to-do-if-mariadb-doesnt-start/) has this to say about this error :

> This is usually a permission error on the directory in which this file is being written. Ensure that the
> entire datadir is owned by the user running mysqld, usually mysql. Ensure that directories have the "x"
> (execute) directory permissions for the owner. Ensure that all the parent directories of the datadir
> upwards have "x" (execute) permissions for all (user, group, and other).

I have done that, and using the command `sudo -u mysql /bin/bash` I have been able to create, edit and save a text file in the `/media/pi/external_drive/mysql_data` directory as the mysql user, yet the error persists.

Edit : This was due to a typo in the directory name (dash instead of underscore). Now the error is gone, but mariadb still doesn't start :

```
mars 08 10:41:26 raspberrypi mysqld[8607]: 2021-03-08 10:41:26 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.27-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as pr
mars 08 10:41:26 raspberrypi mysqld[8607]: 2021-03-08 10:41:26 0 [Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 16384
mars 08 10:41:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=7/NOTRUNNING
mars 08 10:41:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
mars 08 10:41:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.27 database server.
```

Comment: Related : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/638126/chown-silently-failing

Comment: `chown -R mysql:mysql /media/pi/external_drive/mysql-data && chmod -R u=rwX,g=rwX,o= /media/pi/external_drive/mysql-data`

Comment: @JiriB Thanks for the help, the permissions were already correct, but thanks to your answer I was able to see that I had written the directory as mysql-data (dash) instead of mysql_data (underscore). Now the error disappears but it still doesn't launch : 
`mars 08 10:41:26 raspberrypi mysqld[8607]: 2021-03-08 10:41:26 0 [Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 16384
mars 08 10:41:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=7/NOTRUNNING`

Answer (score 0):

The first error was due to a typo (dash instead of underscore). Once that was fixed, I was able to remove the "Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 16384" by adding the following to my.cnf :
open_files_limit = 10000